# Find local max local min for $f(x) = x^2 + 1/x$

Tags: calculus

Find local max local min for $f(x) = x^2 + 1/x$,

I tried to take first order derivative $$ f'(x) = 2x -x^{-2}$$ but how do I go from here.

Comment: Setting that derivative equal to zero.

Comment: @EricS. I see then I got $x = \sqrt[3]{1/2}$ but according to the graph, it should have 2 extrema?

Comment: Are you sure? The one you mentioned really is the only one.

Comment: @EricS. I think you are right, there should be only one extrema

Answer (score 1):

From here you find the zeros of the first derivative. These values of x are the extrema in the function. Next, to determine if the extrema are minima or maxima you take the second derivative and see when $f''(x)>0$ and when $f''(x)<0$. On the intervals when $f''(x)<0$ the graph is concave down so any extrema on these intervals are maxima. On the intervals when $f''(x)>0$ the graph is concave up so any extrema on these intervals are minima.

Answer (score 0):

make the derivative equal to zero.Then find the value of x and put this value in f(x).Double differentiate f(x).If it is less than zero, then it is the maxima and if f"(x)>0,then it is local minima.